# Blender Animal Tracking

Tags: physics, tracking

I'm very new to Blender and this is my second week using it. I'm currently working on a project where I want to track a lion's head in a video and add plants with physics to its head. I have a video of the lion that I'm trying to track:

Video Link:  https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/n2ph8to8gjt14dt74udm8/lionbaset.mp4?dl=0&rlkey=eclwypekrmvt7f69wo3n2xj6i

I'm not very skilled in sculpting, so instead of creating the lion's head from scratch, I found a free model and edited it to resemble the lion's face. Here's the model I'm using:

Model Link: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/qeztv2z7l9s3t9fojpdwe/liontrack.obj?dl=0&rlkey=ftunlq92a72vlio8iuzlb9cyn

However, I'm finding it challenging to find a clear and effective workflow for tracking the lion's head and adding the object constraint to the model. Most of the tutorials I've come across focus on human facial tracking, and I could really use some guidance on the best approach for animal tracking.

I would greatly appreciate any professional help or advice you can provide. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you know with what camera and lens this was shot? Specifically what focallength this would greatly help get a more accurate solve.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking/42332#42332 Here is a guide for tracking

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.